# What is default ActiveRecord isolation level for transaction

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

What is default isolation level for transactions in Ruby on Rails for PostgreSQL or MySQL?

[active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb#L173](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb#L173)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The documentation states:

```
  # If your database supports setting the isolation level for a transaction, you can set
  # it like so:
  #
  #   Post.transaction(isolation: :serializable) do
  #     # ...
  #   end
```

And the code is:

```
def transaction(requires_new: nil, isolation: nil, joinable: true)
```

The default value, is `nil`, which means whatever the default isolation level of the database you are using.

The default value for MySQL is :repeatable_read.

The default value for Postgress is :read_committed.

Comment: Link to the sources: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.8.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb#L260